HAProxy with mysql-check option, not working on mysql 8
I have that config for haproxy, mysql version 8
global
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
defaults
    mode http
    log global
    retries 2
    timeout connect 3000ms
    timeout server 5000ms
    timeout client 5000ms
listen stats
    bind 192.168.1.101:9999
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats uri /stats
    stats auth statadmin:statadminpass
listen mysql-cluster
    bind 192.168.1.101:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql-1 192.168.1.40:3306 check
    server mysql-2 192.168.1.41:3306 check

ERROR Layer7 wrong status: #08004Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
As result all server has status DOWN on STAT page.
I tryed this ALTER USER 'haproxy'@'%'; got this one Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL clien and can login into mysql with haproxy user with following command mysql -u haproxy -p
And tred this ALTER USER 'haproxy'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; got this one Access denied for user 'haproxy'@'192.168.1.41' (using password: NO) in that case I can't login to mysql without password mysql -u haproxy -p

Have you checked whether there's an update to haproxy that contains the updated MySQL library?

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Do you understand that the error message means there's a version incompatibility between the mysql library used by haproxy and the mysql server?

I installed the latest version of Haproxy for Ubuntu 22.04, about incompatibility I didn't find any clues to prove that.

It might depend on the mysql library you're linking with.
